# How To Add Storyboard Constraints For Equal Spaced Buttons

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I am trying to add two buttons to a view that also contains a table view. I want the two buttons to fill the width of the screen for different screen sizes (portrait only). There is a minimum width of say 100 units for the buttons to hold the text, but I would like them to be wider for larger screens. I would like the space between buttons to be at least 20 units and at least 20 units of space between the outside edges. This seems like it should be straight forward, but I can't make sense of the align and pin constraints in the Storyboard auto layout. So far, the tutorials I have seen are confusing and don't seem to cover the right amount of detail to help me. Please provide me with some guidance. Below is the layout before constraints are put in place.

[image]

And here is what the layout would look on a 4" iPhone:

[image]

I have already spent a day trying different combinations of constraints, but continue to have problems. Just when I think I have something that works, it won't build because it says I have conflicts.

I am trying to use the following tools (along with the align tools - not shown) to create the proper constraints. I have tried selecting one or both buttons and then using the editor to set the constraints, but each attempt looks bad. Even when I choose "Reset to Suggested Constraints", I get wacko results. Please help with suggestions on how to accomplish this seemingly basic task.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have:

- Leading for first button 20
- Trailing for second button 20
- horizontal spacing between buttons 20
- equal widths for both buttons
- width >= 150 for each button

[image: constraints]

Comment: The width >= 150 constraint doesn't actually do anything here (except cause constraint conflicts if the view is less than 360 points wide) since there will only be one possible width for the buttons that satisfies the spacing.

Comment: You mentioned that you want a minimum of 150?
Can remove the >= constraints and the buttons will take the whole space being equal to each other no matter of screen width

Comment: Sorry, bad example. I just wanted to pose a basic question of how to have two buttons with a minimum width that expands with wider screens

Comment: Does my solution helped you? What is the final result you want to have? )) i am a little bit confused )

Comment: @AndreiLuca Sorry for the delay. I was out today. Your solution makes sense, but I am still a little confused. What I don't understand is how to create those constraints given the tools provided. For example, how do you use the tools provided by Xcode (shown above) to accomplish your answer (such as setting the width to be >= 150, or setting the horizontal or vertical space to be 20)? Those popups (e.g. "Add New Constraints" or "Add New Alignment Constraints") and pull downs don't provide those options. How did you do it?

Comment: You can add constraints by holding down Ctrl and dragging from one view to another and you'll get a list of constraints you can add when you release the click. The >= constraint I added = constraint then in the right side inspector set to "bigger then or equal" For some constraints you must use the popups.

Comment: @AndreiLuca Ok, that helps. One last question. I am still getting a bunch of orange dimensions surrounding the buttons. For example, if I click on button 1, I see a red box around it. Plus, there is a +26 on the left side of button 1, a +5 on the top, and two +152 between button 1 and 2. My understanding is that that is not good. Your answer does not show those. Did you have to do something to get rid of them and make Xcode happy?

Comment: OK. Orange lines show where your views will be placed. You just need to update frames from third pop-up. If lines are red then some constraints contradict each other. When I add constraints. First I add all my views, drag constraints thinking how things would look then update frames to see if the result is what I expected